# How to change a InfoPath Form Library (Secondary) field before publishing

Tags: infopath, form, library

Looking for help.  As simple as this seems, I don't see how / where to alter the typing error that I created for an InfoPath form field.  I am using MS InfoPath 2013 locally, I have created a web enabled form and I have a 'typo' that I want to change...  I can see the field in the Main Fields library of the form and it is correct, yet in the InfoPath Form Library (Secondary) see the image below, the 'typo' that I corrected on the Main line STILL shows with the incorrect spelling...
My tendencies for accuracy require that I alter this field, any/all guidance is appreciated in advance (this is my first venture into a SharePoint form...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first correct the name of this field (Departament choice) in its list then reconfigure your secondary data connection to reread the list field with the correct field name by doing the following:

- Open your form,
- From above ribbon, > Click on Data Tab.
- Click on data connection> and select your secondary connection, > Click Modify > follow the wizard.

[image]

**Note:** If you add this field in your form and you talk about the display name you can just change the label of this field without changing the field name in the list. it's up to you :).